# Font-face as base64 with fallbacks

Tags: css

Following this [threat](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) I´d like to include a fontface as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); 
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), 
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); 
}
```

But instead of loading files from the filesystem the filecontent is coming from a database as base64 string. My Question is do I have to add the base64 string for each format (woff,woff2,svg,eot,ttf)? like:

```
url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgABA… 
url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgABA… 
url(data:application/x-font-truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,,d09GMgABA… 
url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base648;base64,,d09GMgABA… 
url(data:application/vnd.ms-fontobject;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgABA…
```

I´m asking because when looking at fontsquirrels generated base64 generated stylesheets they only provide one as base64 others as local files.

Comment: You probably realize this, but embedding all formats increases the file size dramatically for users of all browsers. (Maybe fontsquirrel is looking at the tiny market share of browsers not supporting woff and thinking "nope, not worth it".)

Comment: Thanks this could probably be the reason as I could not find any source which includes all format as base64.

Answer (score 2):

Base64 works with ttf-format.

Example:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: "CustomFont";
        src:        url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf8;base64,AAEAAAAQAQAABAAAT...) format("truetype");
    }
```