# Can't include EOT font encoded by base64 to inline CSS

Tags: html, css, base64, font-face, eot

I need to include the Roboto Condensed font in .EOT format for IE 7 within my inline CSS in one HTML file after encoding of the font by base64.

So first I've encoded the font by PHP code

```
<?php
$base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents('roboto-condensed.eot'));
file_put_contents('base64_version.txt', $base64);
?>
```

And I got

```
DGMAA...........mAskA
```

Then I try to include the font as following:

```
<style>
@font-face{
font-family:'Roboto Condensed';
src:url('data:application/x-font-eot;base64,DGMAA...........mAskA') format('embedded-opentype');
}
body{
font-family:'Roboto Condensed';
}
</style>

Some text
```

But the font is not being loaded. However if I include it with

```
src:url('roboto-condensed.eot');
```

it's loaded successfully

I've tried also

```
src:url('data:application/vnd.ms-fontobject;charset=utf-8;base64,DGMAA...........mAskA') format('embedded-opentype'));
```

as mentioned by the link [Font-face as base64 with fallbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32789202/3208225) but without success

Comment: what would be your reason to encode the font in this case, looks like you already have it locally, in that case you could just use the src?

Comment: Yes, I know it, but I need to get the font build-in so that my HTML file would be as "small app" in one file